# Mailer Error: Could not instantiate mail function in joomla

Tags: php, joomla, sendmail, instantiation

I have used following settings in joomla -adminpanel- global configuration-server

```
Mailer  :Sendmail
Mail from   :user
From Name   :sales@user.com
Sendmail Path   :/usr/sbin/sendmail
SMTP Authentication  :No   
SMTP Security   :none
SMTP Port   :25
SMTP Username:
SMTP Password   :
SMTP Host   :localhost
```

I have used form in site

```
   <form action="email.php" method="post" name="emailForm" id="emailForm" class="form-  validate">
```

in email.php i used php mailer as follows

```
<?php
 require_once("class.phpmailer.php");
 $mail = new PHPMailer();$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
 $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
 $name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
 $message = $_REQUEST['text'] ;
                 // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

  $mail->From = 'sales@example.com ';
  $mail->FromName = 'Techzo';
  $mail->addAddress('ccccc@example.in');               // Name is optional

  $mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50     characters
  $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
  $mail->Subject = 'Enquiry /Contact form';
  $mail->Body    = 'Name: $name\nEmail: $email\n\n$message';



if(!$mail->send()) {
echo 'Message could not be sent.';
echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo 'Message has been sent';
 }

?>
```

I have searched and worked accordingly but not in use.As am new to these coding please help me to understand this issue

Comment: Where is the script located?

Comment: Is sendmail properly configured? I would switch to SMTP and use the credentials from an existing email account on the mails server.

Comment: Rather than calling PHPMailer, why don't you use Joomla's built-in mail function? It will make life easier

Comment: Lodder has right, was not realizing that you are using the native PHP Mailer. Use the Joomla mailer app instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when sendmail is not installed on your server (sendmail should be under /usr/sbin ). You will need to install sendmail or use an alternative, such as gmail (you can use gmail using the phpmailer class.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your suggestions.I have sorted out the problem a day before.

Problem is sendmail option is not available in that server, I have tried for SMTP with wrong port no(25) previously.587 is port no for the mail server.

BY USING SMTP with all their configuration settings i done through it.